# Laravel API Authentication api migration table to users failed

Tags: mysql, laravel

step 1. php artisan make:migration add_api_token_to_users_table --table=users.

step 2. insert this to schema table api_token_to_users_table.

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
$table->string('api_token', 80)->after('password')
                    ->unique()
                    ->nullable()
                    ->default(null);
});
```

step 3. run migrate using php artisan migrate.

when I run php artisan migrate I got this error.

PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'after `password`) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' at line 1")

Laravel version 5.8.38

Answer (score 0):

When you use the nullable() method, that field will default set NULL.

Comment: stll not works. btw all steps that I followed is from laravel documentation.

Comment: by this time it works, just came back to do this again and somehow it works. back then I just made some mistake code that I'm not aware.